# Does disks tool erase .shred files?

Tags: secure-erase

Does disks tool erase .shred files?

[image]

Comment: Gnome-Disks will format and zero partitions as well as full disks, but not single files.

Comment: If you choose "erase", it will erase all files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you toggle the option to "Erase" when you are formatting a volume, the following things will happen:

1. The volume will be formatted to the type specified.
2. A `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX` sort of action will take place, where `/dev/sdX` is the newly formatted volume. In plain language, the new volume will have a bunch of zeroes written to it.

[image: Disks Utility]

If you are looking for a *more thorough* means of wiping a hard drive or making it very, very difficult to recover data, you will probably want to use [wipe](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/wipe.1.html), [srm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/srm.1.html), [shred](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/shred.1.html), or [scrub](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/scrub.1.html).

Comment: It's a myth, that zeroing would not be enough. Overwriting with zeros is enough for 99,999999% of people and use cases. (assuming OP does not use magnetic tapes or so). The sentence should begin with "*If you are paranoid ...*"  ;-)

Comment: Never said it would not be enough, just that it would make data recovery very, very difficult 

Comment: It's not *very, very difficult*, it is **impossible**. Even with zeros it is impossible to recover data with modern hard drives.